# Digikam changes several times folder DigiCam where are located all pictures suddently changed to file DigiCam

Tags: digikam

All my photos are located in directory /Pictures/DigiCam/
I use DigiKam software to view and manage my photos.
One day when I launched DigiKam to view and update same pictures, I been notified that working directory does not exist!
While I looked at directory with file manager I saw there **file** named DigiCam instead **directory DigiCam**!.
**Exactly same event happen few mounts ago, on same computer with same software.**

**( This list shows situation after event, please note this is file )**
michael@michael-ThinkPad-T470:/mnt/sda6/michael$ dir Pictures/Dig* -ld -a
-rw-r--r--  1 michael michael 282624 Sep 12 21:58 Pictures/DigiCam

**( This list shows normal situation before event, please note there is directory )**
michael@michael-ThinkPad-T470:/mnt/sda6/michael$ dir Pictures/Dig* -ld -a
drwxrwxr-x 32 michael michael   4096 Sep 13 19:41 Pictures/DigiCam

michael@michael-ThinkPad-T470:/mnt/sda6/michael$ dir Pictures/Dig* -l -a
-rw-r--r--  1 michael michael 282624 Sep 12 21:58 Pictures/DigiCam

Pictures/DigiCam:
total 270360
drwxrwxr-x 32 michael michael      4096 Sep 13 19:41 .
drwxrwxr-x  3 michael michael      4096 Sep 13 19:28 ..
drwxrwxrwx  2 michael michael      4096 Sep  4 20:41 5megacopy
drwxrwxrwx 31 michael michael      4096 Apr 10 15:03 All_Travel
-rwxrwxrwx  1 michael michael  13484032 Sep  4 21:05 digikam4.db
drwxrwxrwx  4 michael michael      4096 Mar 14  2020 .dtrash
drwxrwxrwx  3 michael michael      4096 Sep  4 20:28 Misc
drwxrwxrwx  2 michael michael      4096 Apr  4 10:31 Orly_Eli_Wedding
-rwxrwxrwx  1 michael michael   2789376 Sep  4 21:04 recognition.db
drwxrwxrwx  2 michael michael      4096 Jun 23 21:12 Scaned_Fisa
-rwxrwxrwx  1 michael michael 260411392 Sep  4 21:04 thumbnails-digikam.db
drwxrwxrwx  3 michael michael      4096 May 17  2020 WhatsApp\ Images

Comment: That is certainly a horrible bug. [Digikam suggests](https://www.digikam.org/support/) filing [a bug report here](https://bugs.kde.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided&product=digikam). There’s a bit of friction with the KDE.org account requirement but, given the seriousness of this bug, I’m sure a lot of fellow Digikam users would appreciate it if you reported the problem 

Comment: Thank you, I just re-edit my question, hope it describes better.